# Kubernetes: TLS on an Ingress; hosts using wrong certificate

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, lets-encrypt, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to secure my K8s application with TLS. I've generated 2 SSL certificates with Let's Encrypt: one for kamerbaas.nl and one for gateway.kamerbaas.nl. I created two secrets from the files tls.crt and tls.key for each domain.

The YAML file of my Ingress is as follows:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gateway-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - gateway.kamerbaas.nl
    secretName: gateway.kamerbaas.nl
  - hosts:
    - kamerbaas.nl
    secretName: kamerbaas.nl
rules:
  - host: gateway.kamerbaas.nl
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: kb-gateway
          servicePort: 80
  - host: kamerbaas.nl
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: kb-frontend
          servicePort: 80
```

The catch: When I go to https://gateway.kamerbaas.nl, it works; it's showing a green lock. When I go to https://kamerbaas.nl however, it says it's not secure, since it's trying to use the certificate of gateway.kamerbaas.nl.

I've ruled out the possibility that it's a cache issue, and I've ensured that I didn't mix my certificate files up. I'm 100% sure the secrets are right.

Why is kamerbaas.nl trying to use the certificate of gateway.kamerbaas.nl?

Ps. gateway.kamerbaas.nl has a node-express server running with HTTPS. I've loaded my certificates there as well. kamerbaas.nl has a node server without https, could that be the problem? I'm guessing it doesn't matter, since my Ingress rules only points to port 80 of my services, which is the port for unsecured HTTP.

Comment: While I see that you've followed the instructions from here - https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/ingress/controllers/nginx/examples/multi-tls/multi-tls.yaml ; I hope you're not hitting this issue/bug - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/37518

Comment: An alternative work around might be for you to create a SAN cert with both `gateway.kamerbaas.nl` and `kamerbaas.nl` and use that instead. This is not a fix, but a work around that might be worth trying.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @ffledgling, I think I am running into that issue.

Comment: I think the issue is with annotation "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target". can you check by splitting the rules into two ingress definitions...?

Comment: Did you try to create 2 independent ingresses to each host? Is it working for you?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Have you found a solution? Also what version of kubernetes are you using? It seems that multiple hotsts/tls is supported starting from 1.10 : https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/37518#issuecomment-393130522